# RoR: Fetch data from server not from browser cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app when I use link_to  to change the page (i.e. go back with :back or just return to root_path). My buttons are unclickable. But when I reload page or use redirect_to, i.e when I save something, buttons work properly.
I think the problem is that I fetch data from browser, not from server. I tried to avoid this with this in application_controler.rb:

```
before_filter :set_cache_buster


private
  def set_cache_buster
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
  end
```

But it failed. Nothing happen after click(should submit). Css style works, I mean after click button looks as clicked.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by unclickable? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Are the buttons disabled on submit? Is that why they're unclickable when going back in history?

Comment: Nothing happen after click( should submit), but css style works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by disable turbolinks.